# how to change color of TextinputLayout's edittext underline android

Tags: android

I am using android design library's TextinputLayout. But couldn't customize the underline color of EditText inside TextinputLayout. Please help.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_pincode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_city"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_pincode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Pincode*"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_13sdp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>

</style>
```

Comment: please share screenshot which helps to know better

Comment: Check this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219521/when-edittext-is-select-theme-style-does-not-change/39219679#39219679)

Comment: in your android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout add android:theme="@style/MyAccount" and in your style <style name="MyAccount" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: The only answer that worked for me after Google-ing SO for an hour is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543554/2413303

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout` style, you need to add `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlHighlight`.

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_13sdp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>

    //added attributes
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

**Edited:**

You can remove `colorControlHighlight`. In your case, it is not necessary. `colorControlHightlight` is used to applied color on ripple, list selected etc.

You can refer to @Gaëtan Maisse answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat).

Answer (score 17):

Add this style to your styles.xml file :

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">

        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#e34b1c</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#e34b1c</item>
</style>
```

Then add the 'TextLabel' theme to your textinputlayout as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_pincode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_city"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

...
```

Play around with the colors you want in the styles.xml.

Comment: thanks this worked for me.. best answer so far

Comment: save my day. Thx.

Comment: It caused crash on my side. Plus 'TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout' was defined in @Amad 's answer, not yours, you even have the exact same spelling mistake with his.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to change

```
<color name="colorAccent">#YOURCOLOR</color>
```

Google Material Design always refer to this color, in order to have the same color for "action" everywhere